# "Type Error occurred when creating object: Magento\\Eav\\Model\\Entity\\Attribute\\Source\\Config"

Tags: php, magento-2.3

I migrated from Magento 1.9.1.0 to Magento 2.3.1...the migration was completed with warnings and after I reindexed and flushed cache and also set upgrade, compile, and deploy, Clicking on All Customers at admin backend displays error, can't view all customers and some customer information like the shipping address, billing address, contact, and name is missing from the order page.

I have remigrated countless times with different solutions but I still get the same error.

> {"0":"Type Error occurred when creating object:
>   Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config","1":"#1
>   Magento\Framework\ObjectManager\Factory\Compiled->create('Magento\Eav\Mode...',
>   array()) called at
>   [vendor/magento/framework/ObjectManager/ObjectManager.php:56]\

I was expecting the customer page should load properly and also view all customers shouldn't be giving errors cos I have really gone through hell trying to solve this. I would be grateful for any assistance.

Comment: Perhaps the Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Config constructor takes different parameters between the two versions?

Answer (score 1):

Try to find the `customer_eav_attribute` that `fronted_input` column value is `select` in `eav_attribute`, make sure the column `source_model` is not NULL or empty or the value which refers to a specific class is correct.

If it's empty or NULL, you must be skip/ignore the error warning while migrating. You can solve this by changing the `fronted_input` column value  to `int` until you finish creating the `source_model` class

Comment: Also setting the frontend_input to int or text will do.

Answer (score 0):

Try to debug this class `\Magento\Customer\Model\Metadata\CustomerMetadata` specifically in the method `getAttributeMetadata` using xDebug. There you will find out which `attribute_code` that caused this error. And then as per @Idham Choudry, change the `frontend_input` value of that attribute in `eav_attribute` table. On my end, I changed it to text.